# Как выбрать повторяющиеся значения из бд и вывести одно по условию?

Tags: php, mysql

В таблице есть несколько полей - id, phone, date, ip.
Я сделал выборку по повторяющимся номерам телефона и ip(несколько кусков кода в одном):

```
 <?   $queryPhones = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT phone FROM Users");
    $existedPhones = mysqli_fetch_all($queryPhones, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $queryIPs = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT ip FROM Users");
    $existedIPs = mysqli_fetch_all($queryIPs, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach ($post as $users):
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($existedPhones as $existedPhone) {
    if ($existedPhone['phone'] == $users['phone']) {
    $i++;
            }
               }
    if ($i > 1) { 
    echo $users['phone'];     }
    $a = 0;
    foreach ($existedIPs as $existedIP) {
    if ($existedIP['ip'] == $users['ip']) {
    $a++;
         }
          }
    if ($a > 1) { 
     echo $users['ip'];    }
?>
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как мне вывести информацию о том, что есть запись в таблице с таким же номером или ip, но с id меньшим, чем указан в этом конкретном цикле.

Comment: эту задачу по крайней мере частично можно решить на уровне БД. приведите пример данных в таблице, и желаемый результат, который вы хотите получить.

Comment: id - int с автоинкерементом, остальные строки - varchar, Ip типа 127.0.0.1, phone +7(999)0000000 , date - 2019-04-05.
В результате хочу проверить значения ip и phone, при отсутствии совпадение не выводить ничего, а при совпадении - получить запись с датой, именем и телефоном и id меньшим, чем текущий.

Comment: @web2k17, Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Comment: @SergeyNudnov к сожалению, ваш пример мне не помог и я сделал другим способом :(

Comment: @web2k17 Нет проблем. В любом случае, Ваш отзыв был важен для меня. Очень неприятно помогать людям "в пустоту", без всякой реакции со стороны вопрошающего...

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать такой запрос:

```
SELECT a.id, a.phone, count(*) as row_number
FROM `Users` a
JOIN `Users` b
ON a.phone = b.phone AND a.id >= b.id
GROUP BY a.phone, a.id
ORDER BY a.phone, row_number DESC
```

И аналогичный для IP.

Если в ответе получаете row_number > 1, то следующими строками будут идти дубликаты с меньшими id - до row_number=1.

Посмотрите пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53506c9d/1)